# Single Node Rancher inconsistently goes down

Tags: kubernetes, rancher-rke

I have created rancher with a single node using the minimum cluster.yml as given in rke documentation.
https://rke.docs.rancher.com/example-yamls

I have provisioned a new cluster with 2 machines (master and worker).
I observed that the Rancher UI inconsistently goes down. I tried to check the logs and found out that there was some problem with the cert manager initially for which normal docker restart fixed my problem.

Now I observed that the UI is down and also the kubectl get pods or any other command to get the cluster related information is not working.
[docker ps shown this all containers running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UHzb.png)
I observed not all the containers are coming up.

[kubectl get pods is showing this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArDEZ.png)

I tried to get the latest cluster info using kubectl get pods but it is throwing error as

```
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```